# Expo video-chat with Agora SDK

Tags: expo, agora.io, videochat, agora

I am building an app with expo and I need to have a video chat function. I started using agora UI but the UI is designed the way I wanted it. Is there a way to use agora with Expo without using AgoraUI? If not, is there a better service for expo, one that give me more control over the design?